# Different MySQL versions give different result for LEFT JOIN and ORDER in subquery

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, sql-order-by

Since migrating to MySQL 5.6 i'm having trouble with the order of a joined table.
This worked fine in MySQL 5.1

I want to select every last single picture (highest id) for every category in product_cat_pictures. On every execution of this same query, the order of the pictures for specific categories is different.

```
SELECT c.id, repo.filename FROM product_cat_container AS c
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM product_cat_pictures ORDER BY id DESC) AS p
  ON c.id = p.cat_id
LEFT JOIN picture_repository AS repo
  ON p.picture_id = repo.id
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY c.order


product_cat_container
---------------------
id  name  order


product_cat_pictures 
---------------------
id  cat_id  picture_id


picture_repository 
---------------------
id  filename
```

Comment: Check [12.19.3 MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html).

Answer (score 0):

You used NON-ANSI SQL:

```
SELECT c.id, repo.filename FROM product_cat_container AS c
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM product_cat_pictures ORDER BY id DESC) AS p
  ON c.id = p.cat_id
LEFT JOIN picture_repository AS repo
  ON p.picture_id = repo.id
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY c.order;
```

The `GROUP BY` is only on `c.id`, returning a random value (first accessible value) for repo.filename. This behavior is MySQL version specific.

An ANSI compliant query does not have this random behavior:

```
SELECT c.id, MIN(repo.filename) AS filename FROM product_cat_container AS c
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM product_cat_pictures ORDER BY id DESC) AS p
  ON c.id = p.cat_id
LEFT JOIN picture_repository AS repo
  ON p.picture_id = repo.id
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY c.order;
```

Here the `MIN` function takes care of returning a correct result (the minimum value).

Alternative:

```
SELECT c.id, repo.filename FROM product_cat_container AS c
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM product_cat_pictures ORDER BY id DESC) AS p
  ON c.id = p.cat_id
LEFT JOIN picture_repository AS repo
  ON p.picture_id = repo.id
GROUP BY c.id,repo.filename
ORDER BY c.order;
```

In here the `GROUP BY` has all the columns, resulting possibly in more then 1 result per id, but again it is a ANSI valid (ie: 100% defined) result.

You will have to choose which function/style to use to get your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to add foreign keys and indices, avoiding performance problems if the tables have millions rows.

Try:

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9633d6/3)

```sql
mysql> DROP TABLES IF EXISTS `product_cat_container`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLES IF EXISTS `product_cat_pictures`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLES IF EXISTS `picture_repository`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product_cat_container` (
    ->     `id` INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ->     `name` VARCHAR(25),
    ->     `order` INT UNSIGNED
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product_cat_pictures` (
    ->     `id` INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ->     `cat_id` INT UNSIGNED,
    ->     `picture_id` INT UNSIGNED
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `picture_repository` (
    ->     `id` INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ->     `filename` VARCHAR(25)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `product_cat_container`
    ->     (`name`, `order`)
    -> VALUES
    ->     ('AAA', 1), ('BBB', 2), ('CCC', 3), ('DDD', 4);
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> INSERT INTO `picture_repository`
    ->     (`filename`)
    -> VALUES
    ->     ('AAA'), ('BBB'), ('CCC'), ('DDD'), ('EEE');
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> INSERT INTO `product_cat_pictures`
    ->     (`cat_id`, `picture_id`)
    -> VALUES
    ->     (1, 4), (1, 2), (1, 1), (2, 3), (3, 5), (3, 4);
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `c`.`id`,
    ->   `repo`.`filename`
    -> FROM
    ->   `product_cat_container` `c`
    ->     LEFT JOIN (
    ->                 SELECT
    ->                   `p`.`cat_id`,
    ->                   `p`.`picture_id`
    ->                 FROM
    ->                   `product_cat_pictures` `p`
    ->                     INNER JOIN (
    ->                                 SELECT
    ->                                   MAX(`id`) `id`
    ->                                 FROM
    ->                                   `product_cat_pictures`
    ->                                 GROUP BY
    ->                                   `cat_id`
    ->                                 ) `d` ON `p`.`id` = `d`.`id`
    ->               ) `p` ON `c`.`id` = `p`.`cat_id`
    ->     LEFT JOIN `picture_repository` `repo` ON `p`.`picture_id` = `repo`.`id`
    -> ORDER BY
    ->   `c`.`order`;
+----+----------+
| id | filename |
+----+----------+
|  1 | AAA      |
|  2 | CCC      |
|  3 | DDD      |
|  4 | NULL     |
+----+----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```